# iOS framework: MTLLibrary newFunctionWithName fails when cikernel flag is set on client code

Tags: ios, metal

I have an iOS framework using Metal; it sets up a pipeline descriptor as follows:

```
...
_metalVars.mtlLibrary = [_metalVars.mtlDevice newLibraryWithFile:libraryPath error:&error];

id <MTLFunction> vertexFunction = [_metalVars.mtlLibrary newFunctionWithName:@"vertexShader"];
id <MTLFunction> fragmentFunction = [_metalVars.mtlLibrary newFunctionWithName:@"fragmentShader"];

MTLRenderPipelineDescriptor *pipelineStateDescriptor = [[MTLRenderPipelineDescriptor alloc] init];

MTLRenderPipelineDescriptor *pipelineStateDescriptor = [[MTLRenderPipelineDescriptor alloc] init];
pipelineStateDescriptor.label = @"MyPipeline";
pipelineStateDescriptor.vertexFunction = vertexFunction;
pipelineStateDescriptor.fragmentFunction = fragmentFunction;
pipelineStateDescriptor.vertexDescriptor = mtlVertexDescriptor;
pipelineStateDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].pixelFormat = MTLPixelFormatRGBA8Unorm; 

_metalVars.mtlPipelineState = [_metalVars.mtlDevice newRenderPipelineStateWithDescriptor:pipelineStateDescriptor error:&error];
...
```

This framework is used by an iOS app, and has been working fine until the flag

```
-fcikernel
```

was set under Other Metal Compiler Flags, and

```
-cikernel
```

underOther Metal Linker Flags, ***in the client app's Build Settings***.
(flags set on client, per https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreimage/cikernel/2880194-kernelwithfunctionname.)

With those changes in the client app, the above framework code snippet now fails at the last line of the above code snippet, on the call to `newRenderPipelineStateWithDescriptor` with the error

```
validateWithDevice:2556: failed assertion `Render Pipeline Descriptor Validation
vertexFunction must not be nil
```

and I've verified that the framework is now returning nil for the vertex function at

```
id <MTLFunction> vertexFunction = [_metalVars.mtlLibrary newFunctionWithName:@"vertexShader"];
```

but works fine if I remove the flags on the client app.

Questions:
1.)  I've understood that metal shaders were precompiled; why would changing a build setting on the *client* code cause this runtime failure in the *unchanged* framework?
2.)  How can this be resolved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those flags are meant to be used when compiling Core Image kernels written in Metal. They change the way the code is translated in a way that is not compatible with "regular" Metal shader code.

The problem with setting the Core Image flags on the project level is that all `.metal` files are affected—regardless of whether they contain Core Image kernels or regular shader code.

The best way around this is by using a different file extension for files containing Core Image Metal kernels, like `.ci.metal`. Then custom build rules can be used to compile those kernels separately from the rest of the Metal codebase.
I recommend [this session](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2020/10021/) from WWDC 2020 which describes the process in detail.

Comment: Perfect - that fixed it.